# I am not able to login to Ubuntu shell , because I am not given any chance to write my password

Tags: command-line

Sir I was not able to see my login screen so I switched to shell.
Whenever I enter my username and press enter, the cursor never stop or wait for me to enter password, so I can not enter my password. And a loop of login incorrect occurs for 4 times.
When I am in recovery mode it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the password using passwd command and login again. If not again possible share me the screenshot of the problem.